# IOS: Tapku calendar: starting week on Sunday, or not, depending on user choice

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, tapku

I am using tapku calendar in my project.  I need to make an option for the user to start week on Sunday or on Monday.
There is a method in viewDidLoad:

```
(id)initWithSunday:(BOOL)sundayFirst
```

Is there a way to update the calendar with new option?  I tried calling initWithSunday with new value and [calendar reload], but errors occurred.

Comment: What errors occurred?

Comment: I can set the initial value(in viewDidLoad), but can’t change it later(example:after closing settings). If I call

calendar=[calendar initWithSundayAsFirst:startWhithSunday];

the calendar becomes grey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.
The calendar subview must be removed from superview, set to nil, and added again.

```
[calendar removeFromSuperview]; 
calendar= nil; 

calendar =  [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] initWithSundayAsFirst:startWhithSunday];
calendar.delegate = self;
calendar.dataSource = self;
calendar.frame = CGRectMake(14, 11, calendar.frame.size.width, calendar.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:calendar];
[calendar reload];
```